# Whats is a viable approach for a Template Data Model consists of two lists?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

At the moment im working on a project where you can create a template for a report. At this point im struggling between two viable approaches for the entity model and I'm not sure which way is from the architectural approach the way to go.

A template consists of the following attributes:

- Id
- Name
- List of Materials
- List of Services

For each material and service position I have to declare a count of how many is needed.

I have two approaches how I can build it:

*Approach I:*

```cs
    public class Template
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TemplatePosition> Positions { get; set; }

    }
    public class TemplatePosition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }
        public Material Material { get; set; }
        public Template Template { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public TemplatePositionTyp Type => this.Material != null ? TemplatePositionTyp.Material : TemplatePositionTyp.Service;
    }

    public enum TemplatePositionTyp
    {
        Material = 1,
        Service = 2
    }
```

*Approach II:*

```cs
    public class Template
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TemplateMaterialPosition> MaterialPositions { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TemplateServicePosition> ServicePositions { get; set; }
    }
    public class TemplateMaterialPosition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Material Material { get; set; }
        public Template Template { get; set; }
   }
    public class TemplateServicePosition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }
        public Template Template { get; set; }
   }
```

I wish someone can explain me which one is the one to go and even the downside of the other approach.

Comment: It is a speed verses amount of memory required.  When you have a database creating a single table takes more memory because data gets duplicated.  For example if a person has an ID, First Name, Last Name.  With one table you always have to add all three items.  If you have a two tables you can have only ID in First table and then look up First and Last Name by ID.  Having two tables queries takes longer because you have to join the two tables by ID.  Your approach 2 will not work because you cannot join your two tables by anything unique.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer. I see what you mean and I also see that my explanation was maybe a bit confused. I'm sorry for that! Let me try again: I don't need a relation between Service and Material. In approach 1 TemplatePosition can have only have Material or Service the other needs to be null. At this point I'm already unsure if this pattern is really acceptable. Approach 2 shows more a DB releated view without Model Logic.

Comment: Database these days are flat items (rows and columns) and do not have links.  So first you have to consider the type of database you are using and if the database supports links between tables.  You also have to consider how you put data into the database as well as removing data.  And consider if the database is constant (never adding additional items) or is dynamic.  And speed verses memory.  Having ICollection in database (links) means you are doing the joining of tables during writing instead of reading.  So your write time is longer but read time is shorter.  You are still joining.

Comment: When you write to a database you normally just write to the end of the table without any lookup.  Using the ICollection means you have to do lookup during the writes which takes longer.